# TFS: How do I get a list of managed files in my enlistment?

Tags: tfs, mercurial, tf-cli

In tfs, how do I get a list of files in my working directory that are being managed by tfs? I don't care if I've checked them out or not (if I did, `tf status` would be the obvious choice). I just care whether or not tfs is tracking changes for them or not.

I want to use this like I use `hg locate` for Mercurial. I want to search through all the files that are not temporary files or build products of some kind, things that are part of the base source code, for something that shows up in the build products, but I don't know where it comes from.

Comment: I'm curious as to why the downvote with no comment on how my question could be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [LocalVersions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee791979(v=vs.100).aspx) command. (The newly be added file won’t be list)

Comment: The output of this is a pain to parse, but it does the job. It's too late for the task I asked the question for, which is why it took me so long to get back to it. But it is a valid answer to my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**tf workflod**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/workfold-command) command. Which could **displays information about the mappings** between your workspace folders and the folders on the server for Team Foundation version control.

The following command displays the working folder mappings for the workspace in the current directory:

```
C:\projects>tf workfold
```

If you want to list the working folder mappings for a different workspace, you can specify the `/workspace:workspacename` parameter.

```
C:\>tf workfold /workspace:My_Other_Workspace
```

---

***Required Permissions***

To use the **workfold** command, you must be the owner of the specified or implied workspace or have the global **Administer workspaces** permission set to **Allow**.

Comment: That command does work for me, but the list I get is not helpful. It's basically a list of top-level directories, but no listing if the files being managed. It's nice to see, and might be of help in debugging certain kinds of issues with what's being mapped into my enlistment. But... it doesn't help with what I'm trying to do.